# What rights do you need to have in Team Foudation Server to add a SOAP event handler

Tags: soap, tfs

I would like users do to it themselves, but I don't want everyone to be an adminstrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user does need to be a TFS administrator to add a SOAP event handler.  To work around this, you could write your own webservice that impersonates a TFS admin and lets the caller register their handler.

[Here's a URL that has code similar to this.](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2007/09/07/TFS-Event-Handler-in-NET-3-5-Part-2-Handling-Team-Foundation-Server-Events.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
''' <summary>
''' This is the service contract for integrating with the Team Foundation Server notification events.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<ServiceContract(Namespace:="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03")> _
Public Interface INotification

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The Notify method if fired whenever a subscribed event arrives.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="eventXml">This XML defines the data that was changed on the event.</param>
    ''' <param name="tfsIdentityXml">This XML identifies the Team Foundation Server the event came from.</param>
    ''' <param name="SubscriptionInfo">Information about the subscriber</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <OperationContract( _
                    Action:="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03/Notify", _
                    ReplyAction:="*" _
                    )> _
    <XmlSerializerFormat( _
                    Style:=OperationFormatStyle.Document _
                    )> _
    Sub Notify(ByVal eventXml As String, ByVal tfsIdentityXml As String, ByVal SubscriptionInfo As SubscriptionInfo)

End Interface
```